# Error writing data to buffer: urdf model in rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to spawn a URDF model in RVIZ. However, rviz only displays the axes of each link and thus I cannot see the links. These links are build up from .stl files.

Furthermore I get the following error message in my terminal:
../../intel/intel_bufmgr_gem.c:1158: Error writing data to buffer 67: (0 135936) Bad address .

My computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad T510. It has an i5 processor and has an Integrated Graphics Controller. I am running ROS on Ubuntu 10.10

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10982/error-writing-data-to-buffer:-urdf-model-in-rviz/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2011-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turned out that an update to Ubuntu 11.04 solved the problem. Probably my graphics drivers were outdated

---

Originally posted by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) with karma: 130 on 2011-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2